# optimizing LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN filter using ldap3

Tags: python, optimization, active-directory, ldap

I am using the code snippet below to recursively get all the members of an AD group including nested groups using `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN`. I'm using the LDAP3 python library, the current setup is very slow, takes over two minutes, even for groups with no more than 2 layers deep (of nested groups).

I do get the result I'm looking for after the two minutes wait, but, I want to believe it normally shouldn't take that long.

Is the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` inherently slow, or am I writing the LDAP filter query wrong?

I'm looking for any way to optimize the query.

```py
server = Server(myserver, get_info=SCHEMA)
conn = Connection(server,'username', 'password', client_strategy=SAFE_RESTARTABLE)
status, result, response, _ = conn.search(search_base='dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx', search_filter='(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=group_name,ou=xx-xxxx,ou=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx)', attributes = "*")
print(response)
```

Comment: Refine (narrow) the search base if you can (eg. something like `ou=Users,dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx`), by passing only the domain components, you are searching the entire ldap tree. Also you can check how much time it takes to get all users, without the recursive membership filter : `conn.search('dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=xx', '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))', attributes=['sAMAccountName'])`, so that you can conclude whether that filter is involved or not. I would also compare queries requesting `attributes=['sAMAccountName']` vs `attributes=['*']` (a single or just a few attrs vs all user attrs).

Comment: On large Microsoft Active Directory instances and/or deep-nested groups this is typical.

On some the results may not be complete or may not return at all.

Comment: In most cases it’s better to query membership manually, e. g. https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/11/30/find-all-members-of-group.html